# Forward selection, using adjusted R square or t statistics?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, regression-coefficients, stepwise-regression

When it comes to select variable in multiple regression model using forward selection, should we add variables in the models according to its adjusted R square or t statistics/Sig?

Comment: Neither. You should add variables by model testing using Likelihood Ratio Tests. You could also use information criterions like AIC, BIC.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Note that significance testing will be invalid after stepwise model selection, whether done through $R^2$, $t$ statistics, Likelihood Ratio tests or information criteria.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply whatever rule you want. If you can validate that it works (e.g., holdout set, bootstrap, cross validation), then this kind of stepwise regression [could be competitive with other predictive modeling techniques](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/594106/247274). More typical approaches would be based on Akaike or Bayesian information criteria, however, such as what is performed in the `stepAIC` function in R software.

Keep in mind, though, that extreme care is required to have the desired properties. Software might report values like adjusted $R^2$ and coefficient confidence intervals, but these are misleading. This is related to points 1, 2, 3, 4, and 7 [here](https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/statistics/stepwise-regression-problems/).